# JUNG layout question

Tags: java, jung

I have some graph, which I want to display using [JUNG2](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) like in the image below.

[image]

I've played with some layouts of JUNG2, but I'm always getting an image like this:

[image]

Is it possible to lay out the graph as I wish without writing a new layout?

Thanks in advance

Dmitri

UPD: Here is the code I used for visualizing the graph:

```
private Embedded createSampleGraph() {
Embedded imageComponent = null;

try {
    final DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory =
            DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
    final DocumentBuilder docBuilder =
            docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    final Document document = docBuilder.newDocument();
    final Element svgelem = document.createElement("svg");
    document.appendChild(svgelem);

    final SVGGraphics2D graphic2d = new SVGGraphics2D(document);

    final Graph<String, String> graph = createGraph();
    final VisualizationImageServer<String, String> server =
            createServer(graph);

    server.printAll(graphic2d);

    final Element el = graphic2d.getRoot();
    el.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", "0 0 350 350");
    el.setAttributeNS(null, "style", "width:100%;height:100%;");

    final ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    final Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(bout, "UTF-8");
    graphic2d.stream(el, out);

    final JungResource source = new JungResource(bout);

    TPTApplication.getCurrentApplication().addResource(source);

    imageComponent = new Embedded("", source);

    imageComponent.setWidth(DEFAULT_WIDTH_PIXELS, UNITS_PIXELS);
    imageComponent.setHeight(DEFAULT_HEIGHT_PIXELS, UNITS_PIXELS);
    imageComponent.setMimeType("image/svg+xml");
    addComponent(imageComponent);
} catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException exception) {
    LOGGER.error(ErrorCodes.M_001_UNSUPPORTED_ENCONDING, exception);
} catch (final SVGGraphics2DIOException exception) {
    LOGGER.error(ErrorCodes.M_002_SVG_GRAPHICS_2D_IO, exception);
} catch (final ParserConfigurationException exception) {
    LOGGER.error(ErrorCodes.M_003_PARSER_CONFIGURATION, exception);
}
return imageComponent;
}

private VisualizationImageServer<String, String> createServer(
    final Graph<String, String> aGraph) {
final Layout<String, String> layout = new FRLayout<String, String>(
        aGraph);

layout.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
final VisualizationImageServer<String, String> vv =
        new VisualizationImageServer<String, String>(
                layout, new Dimension(350, 350));
vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(
        new ToStringLabeller<String>());
return vv;
}

private Graph<String, String> createGraph() {
final Graph<String, String> graph =
        new DirectedSparseMultigraph<String, String>();
final String vertex1 = "IE";
final String vertex2 = "P1";
final String vertex3 = "P2";
final String vertex4 = "P3";
final String vertex5 = "FE";

graph.addVertex(vertex1);
graph.addVertex(vertex2);
graph.addVertex(vertex3);
graph.addVertex(vertex4);
graph.addVertex(vertex5);

graph.addEdge("1", vertex1, vertex2, EdgeType.DIRECTED);
graph.addEdge("2", vertex2, vertex3, EdgeType.DIRECTED);
graph.addEdge("3", vertex3, vertex5, EdgeType.DIRECTED);
graph.addEdge("4", vertex1, vertex4, EdgeType.DIRECTED);
graph.addEdge("5", vertex4, vertex5, EdgeType.DIRECTED);
return graph;
}
```

UPD 17.03.2011

Now I can draw a graph like this:

[image]

Comment: your images didn't show up...they became 1 x 1 images... is http://i.imgur.com/ a personal storage website?

Comment: nevermind... it seems that my office firewall blocks links to i.imgur.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pin the locations of specific vertices, do the following for each one after creating the `Layout` and before adding it to the `VisualizationViewer`/`VisualizationImageServer`:

```
layout.setLocation(v, location);
layout.lock(v, true);
```

http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/layout/Layout.html

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with how you create your vertices and edges in JUNG.

For a headstart, I suggest you to refer to createVertices() and createEdges() methods in the JUNG example **WorldMapGraphDemo.class** in **edu.uci.ics.jung.samples** package under the **jung-samples-2.0.1.jar** from your JUNG 2.0 Framework library.

The approach used in the methods are clearer compared to other provided examples where it uses the Map objects to store user-defined vertices and edges information. The rest uses random-generated, library-generated or file-generated information.

Once it is clear to you, you can refer to **PluggableRendererDemo.class** to improve your graph (like decorating **Transformer** and **Renderer** classes under respective packages **edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.decorators** and  **edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.renderers** for decorating and rendering vertex, edge, direction arrow, shape, size, etc.)

Comment: Thanks. I understand the basics of JUNG2, but I don't understand what transforms I need to apply to my graph so that, for example, a) the IE node is placed at the left-most position of the graph and vertically centered (with respect to all other nodes, except FE) and b) the FE node is placed at the right-most position and vertically centered (with respect to all other nodes, except IE). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Ok...Now, I understand what you really want to solve. Dmitri, you can check another JUNG example, **L2RTreeLayoutDemo.class**...it looks so close to what you want to achieve.

Or, you can study SO post below:
[Can Jung graphics appear in the same place every time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297315/cand-jung-graphics-apear-in-the-same-place-every-time)

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I actually looked at L2RTreeLayoutDemo and now I can visualize trees (see the last image in my message). However, the problem is that a project network is not a tree. All "final" nodes are connected to the "final event" node. Is there a way to somehow re-use the code of TreeLayout for non-trees?

Comment: @Dmitri: In that case, you cannot use `Tree` or `Forest` class...Possibly, you can use the `StaticLayout` layout as in **WorldMapGraphDemo.class** example and modify it to position your nodes on a M x N grid (where each node position will be at its respective grid point of the layout)

Comment: Are there any other solutions (like configuring FRLayout so that it does what I want) ? I know about that grid algorithm, but I'd prefer not to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @Dmitri: you can modify any of the layout classes from JUNG sources and create your own but it will take a little bit of study...I do find out some open-source projects create their own JUNG layout algorithms. I haven't explored fully JUNG to be able to come up with my own layout algorithm yet...

Comment: @Dmitri please did you find solution for this ! I need this for my Project

Comment: @Hedouda I don't remember any more. But if you need really badly, you can look at my code and figure out for yourself, whether and how I solved it back then. Here's the link: https://altruix.wordpress.com/portfolio/project-control-center/